# Pop-Up not working correctly in IE

Tags: html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer

I am working on a pop-up, it works correctly on all browsers including IE but on IE9 it is showing space for the "overlay" div. The div is making its space on the browser.

My CSS code for the pop-up is:

> ```
>  .popup
>
>     {  
>         width:500px;
>         height:300px;
>         border:1px solid white;
>         background-color:white;
>         top:20%;
>         position:relative;
>         margin: 0 auto;
>         background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
>         border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189,0.8);
>         -webkit-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),    0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
>            -moz-box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),    0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
>                 box-shadow: 0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7),    0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset;
>         -webkit-box-shadow: 10px;
>         -moz-border-radius: 10px;
>              border-radius: 10px;
>              opacity:1;
>             
>     }
>     #overlay
>     {
>         position:absolute;
>         top:0px;
>         visibility:hidden;
>         background-color:black;
>         opacity:1;
>         left:0px;
>         height:100%;
>         width:100%;
>         text-align:center;
>     }
>     #overlay:target
>     {
>         visibility:visible;
>         -webkit-animation: fade 400ms ease;
>     }
>     #overlay:target > .popup
>     {
>         
>          -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 400ms ease;
>     }
>     @-webkit-keyframes fade
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-webkit-keyframes moveFromBottom
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-moz-keyframes fade
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-moz-keyframes moveFromBottom
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-ms-keyframes fade
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-ms-keyframes moveFromBottom
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-o-keyframes fade
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @-o-keyframes moveFromBottom
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>      @keyframes fade
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
>     
>     
>     @keyframes moveFromBottom
>     {
>         from {
>            
>            
>             -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
>             opacity: 0;
>         }
>         to {
>             
>             -webkit-transform: scale(1);
>             opacity: 1;        
>         }
>     }
> ```

My HTML code is:

> ```
>   <a href="#overlay">Login</a> 
>   <div id="overlay">
>   <div class="popup">
>                     ---                   
>   </div> 
>   </div>
> ```

Comment: "it shows a line below the link" - Which link? And are you saying the link is underlined?

Comment: Please specify which version(s) of IE you're having problems with. Also please clarify what you mean by "a line below the link"; the meaning isn't clear. Finally, please provide the actual HTML code that the browser sees, not the ASP code (which really doesn't help with debugging browser bugs).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `text-decoration: none` to remove the line?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is to simple, but you need to add the style on the a tag `text-decoration: none`

So in your case:

```
 a {
        text-decoration: none
   }
```

Although this is a bad idea, targeting all links.

I personally would just add a class to the sepesific link and target that:

**MarkUp**

```
<a href="#overlay" class="plainlink">Login</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.plainlink {
        text-decoration: none
   }
```

Comment: The above solution is not working. Check out the question again, I have edited it.